# KSQL Submitting multiple queries and keep it running

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I am planning to use KSQL for stream processing. I have following requirements.

- Once query is set up I want to grab that output from query and send it as JSON to RabbitMQ.
- I have multiple users who will be creating criterias for query and I will be taking that criteria and convert into KSQL and submit to KSQL engine. I want to do that on the fly so that I don’t have to keep interjecting myself whenever they new filter requirement. I will be creating UI tool to capture their criteria and my program will convert that into KSQL query.

Also I want to save these queries from multiple users so that when system restart I can submit these queries again

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: 1. Why are you sending data from KSQL to RabbitMQ? Why not consume it from the Kafka topic directly instead?

Comment: 2. Not sure if you second bullet point is asking a question? Seems to be a statement of a system you plan to build. Please clarify if there is an actual question.

Comment: Our current architecture is built around rabbit mq. So what I want was to generated output of KSQL I will send on RabbitMQ and will be consumed by my other process. I can send on Kafka Topic also. I am fine with that.

Comment: Also regarding second bullet point; I want to have system where my tool will interpret my users criteria’s and then convert into KSQL; I want to submit these queries to KSQL without I have to type it on KSQL Console. I need a way to submit/stop/new queries to KSQL session. Also I want to save these queries; so when system restarts it will load those queries again and start running on defined streams.  I hope I have made my question clear.

Comment: You're not really asking a question. You're making a statement of a set of requirements for which you want to build a tool. What is your question that you want people to answer?

Comment: Can I submit queries to KSQL engine through some API or I have to keep using console when every new queries needs to be set up ?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I submit queries to KSQL engine through some API or I have to keep using console when every new queries needs to be set up ?

Yes, there is a REST API, and you can also submit a SQL file to the server to run it headless.